# Java: Cut item from JTree with lazy-deleting

Tags: java, tree, copy-paste, jtree, drag-and-drop

I've implemented Drag'n'Drop and CCP on my JTree (I've created my Transferable and TransferHandler classes).
By default Cut action (CTRL-X or SHIFT+DELETE keys) delete item from JTree (JTreeModel), but I want just to mark it with gray color and delete it only **after Paste action**.
How could I make Cut action to avoid deleting items?

I don't know all the magic of swing DnD, but it looks like Cut action is implemented in TransferHandler.getCutAction()

Answer (score 2):

Kill me please, everything works fine by default. The reason was in my code.

Comment: as the defendant had pleaded guilty...he is hereby acquitted of all crimes claimed by the plaintiff...:)